# What does System Snapshot Mounted mean?

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

Installed macOS Ventura on external USB-C SSD.

Install went as expected but, when I look at “macOS” disk in “Disk Utility” app, I notice “macOS” disk is mounted as a snapshot.

Is that normal? If not, what is going on?

Thanks for helping out!

[image: System Snapshot Mounted]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal. It means your OS disk is snapshotted upon startup and run from the snapshot. This allows changes (ie. system updates) to occur while the system is booted, since the snapshot remains unchanged.